# Apache POI for PPT

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

My task is to transfer dynamic data to ppt, but using the examples from apache I am able to deal with only a single slide. Can you help with transferring the data to next slide, if this slide is filled (like it works in Microsoft Word when page is finished). The data that can be filled in the present slide should stay there and the rest should go to next slide)

Comment: This is not possible as it is also not possible in PowerPoint. In PowerPoint you have to see when the page is full and the text within the text box exceeds the boundary of your slide. You can determine the distance to bottom with 'XSLFTextShape.getBottomInset()' and check if a new slide is needed.

Comment: Thanks, But when dynamic data is getting filled and the size of data can't be predicted. The number of iterations to be done will be humongous. But it looks like the API implementation is just like Power Point and my requirement even when doing in Power Point, requires me to explicitly create a slide.
Any other solutions are appreciated.

Comment: I think this facility was not provided because, it is not possible to do this while manually filling the ppt slide also. when you come to the end of ppt end and keep typing, it won't move to next slide, the text just slides under.